# Best way to inject dependency at runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

`DataAccessLayer.cs` in `DataAccess` project:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

`IDataAccessLayer.cs` in `DataAccess.Contracts` project:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
```

`MainClass.cs` in `Main` project:

```
class Program
{
    public static IFoo Foo { get; set; } // Her I want to inject dependency directly at runtime

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

I want to inject the dependency in `Foo` property directly at runtime.

I would like to use a configuration file instead of attributes for do mapping between class and interface if possible.

What is the best way to do this? How to do this with Unity if possible?

Comment: So you want to use an instance of DataAccessLayer in your Main function ?

Comment: @VasilutLucian Yes

Comment: Dependency Injection is about creating a *loosely coupled* application that allows dependencies to be injected (normally through a class constructor). Part of this process is to limit the design, including removing static variables (or properties) and replacing them with *lifetime management* of a DI container. So, no you can't just throw any design out there and expect Dependency Injection to adapt to it, you need to adapt the design to be DI-friendly. Read [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) for DI-friendly design understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can install from the NuGet package the Unity. Then, you simply can do something like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IDataAccessLayer, DataAccessLayer>();
        var instancerOfDataAccessLayer = unityContainer.Resolve<IDataAccessLayer>();
        instancerOfDataAccessLayer.Foo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

More information about Unity you can find here: http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2014/01/23/introduction-to-dependency-injection-with-unity.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works. But my main project must have references to `DataAccess project` and `DataAccess.Contracts project`. So what is the point of doing this instead of doing it directly `var instance = new DataAccessLayer()` in this case ?

Comment: In your case is ok creating directly an instance of `DataAccessLayer`. But in more complex application the Dependency Injection principle is very used (you can read on the internet about it). Also, if you want to test some big app it is very useful to have DI, you can create mock repository, and other things. You asked for an example using Unity for your example, and this is a small part of the power of DI :)

Comment: Thanks for your very comprehensive answer. Is it possible in my main method to inject dependencies to all the properties of my main project ? For example in my main project I have a log class which contains `IDataAccessLayer` property

Comment: Yes. It is possible. I don't know how your code looks but you can instantiate the interface of `IDataAccessLayer' with Unity and then to give this value to your property from the `Log` class. Also, you can start using DI, injecting the interface in your constructor (in the `Log` class). You can find a lot of example on the internet. In this way you don't need anymore properties, and it will be more easy to understand the code.

Comment: Now, I have a configuration file with `<register type="IDataAccessLayer" mapTo="DataAccessLayer">`. In my main method I have `(UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity").Configure((IUnityContainer)container);` and in my `Log` class `public IDataAccessLayer Dal { get; set; }` And I want to inject dependency in `Dal` property from Main method. I don't find how to do this

Comment: You can instantiate the `Log` class: `var logger = new Log()` and then you can make something like this: `logger.Dal = instanceOfDataLayer`, where `instanceOfDataLayer` is obtained with the Unity, with DI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136048/discussion-between-azerty123-and-vasilut-lucian).

Comment: But if I want to use Log class elsewhere than in my main method? In another class of my main project ? It's not possible to inject directly the dependency at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.

Comment: How to do this ? What are the instructions to put in my main method?...

Comment: I will explain you: [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136048/discussion-between-azerty123-and-vasilut-lucian]